# How does (?:\;jsessionid=[^\?#]*)? in a regular expression work?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Suppose I have this text to match:

```
http://localhost:8080/start.jsp;jsessionid=9E4CDB636248C9610F57704E5E07F782?whatever=true&somethingelse=true
```

Using this regular expression:

```
^(.*?start\.jsp)(?:\;jsessionid=[^\?#]*)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$
```

The resulting groups are:

1. `http://localhost:8080/start.jsp`
2. `?whatever=true&somethingelse=true`

A. Why isn't group number 2 this: `;jsessionid=9E4CDB636248C9610F57704E5E07F782`?
What does this part `?:\` at the beginning of second group do?

B. And also, how can I create an expression to extract the same groups as for the example above, if my options are `begin.jsp` and `start.jsp` (not just `start.jsp`) before the `jsessionid` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `(?: )` is syntax for a non-capturing group. As the name explains it doesn't capture its match.
2. put alternate matching non-capturing group: `(.*?(?:start|begin)\.jsp)`